# Issue retrieving the XML data passed to stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass an XML string to stored procedure and i am unable to retrieve the values from XML and insert into the temp table. I am given my stored procedure below. Can anyone suggest what can be done?

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_InsertTaskRequest_dummy --'<PR><ID>6</ID><ID>7</ID></PR>'
  @ProofReaders XML
AS
/*
  @ProofReaders : <PR>
                  <ID>6</ID>
                  <ID>7</ID>
              </PR>
*/
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PRTable TABLE(Id int)

    INSERT INTO @PRTable
    SELECT Tbl.Col.value('@ID', 'int')
    FROM @ProofReaders.nodes('//PR') Tbl(Col)

    SELECT * FROM @PRTable


END
```

Comment: "unable"?    What error do you get?

Comment: You are trying to read the `@ID` as an at atribute of `<PR>`, but it is an element `<ID>` below `<PR>` actually. As this is the repeating part, you must go with `.nodes()` down to this element: `.nodes('/PR/ID')`. Then you can use `text()[1]` within value .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

**Example**

```
Declare @XML xml = '<PR><ID>6</ID><ID>7</ID></PR>'

Select ID = x.n.value('.','int')
 From  @Xml.nodes('PR/ID') x(n)
```

**Returns**

```
ID
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax you're after is this:

```
DECLARE @ProofReaders xml = '<PR><ID>6</ID><ID>7</ID></PR>';

SELECT PR.ID.value('(text())[1]','int') AS ID
FROM @ProofReaders.nodes('PR/ID') PR(ID)
```

The SQL Server docs do document the use of `value()` quite well. if you get stuck ythey should be your first call: [value() Method (xml Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type)